# The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Code first approach. how can i fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming "Modified" column is a date time field in the table which is mandatory column.

You can resolve this issue in two ways

1. You can pass the "Modified" column field each time you do a insert.
2. Alter the column to accept null values if that field is not mandatory. Following is 
    sql query you can run to change the column to accept null values.

   ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN myColumn {DataType} NULL

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rama. But I don't want Null. It should get the modified date and time in my case this is not inserting date time.

Comment: Hi @MeghaMisra, in that case please check if there is some value passed while executing insert statement. Since the error clearly says that the modified column has been passed with value null. If you can show your implementation that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answer. Modified column was created through migration history in MVC. I created default constrain for Modified column in SQL Server after that change am not having any issue.